# Align row form group elements to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want the input-group element and button to be aligned right. I used float-right to form and specified width. I want the col button to occupy only the size of the button and the remaining col to input element. I do not want to specify any width or fixed col size to elements.

Is it possible to make the col button to occupy only the button width and the remaining col to be occupied by input elements

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div> -->
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control border-basic" id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search Reports..">
    </div>

    <div class="col-8">
    
      <form class="float-right" method="post" style="width:50%">
        <div class="form-group row text-right">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="input-group" style="text-align:right;">
              <input class="form-control border-info"  type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter here" required>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-danger border-info" type="button" title="Clear">
                  <i class="fa fa-close fa-lg"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Create</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4fn1sz30/39/

Comment: can you provide a diagram of what you would like to see.  Your explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-auto` instead. This allows the column to shrink to the width of its content:

```
<div class="col-auto">
     <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Create</button>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/p1nMc2m3gU

Answer (score -1):

Changed `col-4` to `col-md-4, col-sm-4, col-xs-4` and `col-md-8, col-sm-8, col-xs-8`.

Exactly `col-4` is not bad. But I think you are using Bootstrap to create a responsive web. So it is ideal to specify the `col` size for each device resolution.